# Repeat a command every x interval of time in terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, monitoring

How can I **repeat** a command every interval of time , so that it will allow  me to run commands for **checking**  or **monitoring**  directories ?

There is no need for a script, i need just a simple command to be executed in terminal.

Answer (score 269):

You can use  `watch` command, **watch** is used to run any designated command at regular intervals.

Open Terminal and type:

```
watch -n x <your command>
```

change **x** to be the time in seconds you want.

For more help using the `watch` command and its options, run `man watch` or visit this [Link](http://www.linfo.org/watch.html).

**For example :** the following will list, every **60s**, on the same Terminal, the contents of the Desktop directory so that you can know if any changes took place:

```
watch -n 60 ls -l ~/Desktop
```

Comment: +1 but be careful when using expansions. For example, try the difference between `watch -n 1 'echo $COLUMNS'` and `watch -n 1 echo $COLUMNS` when resizing your terminal - the former is expanded every second, but the latter is expanded only once *before* `watch` starts.

Comment: Problem I have with this solution is that you can't run watch as a process and just leave it running in the background (for example with &disown)

Comment: Is there any way to use `watch` with "history enabled" type command?  I love using `watch`, but sometimes I'd prefer to see a log of previous executions as well, instead of just the last one.  And yes, I know I can use scripting (`while true`) to accomplish this, but using the `watch` utilitiy is so much cleaner!

Comment: this worked for simpler commands but with pipelined commands chaining this didn't work  for me..

following was the command I tried
=>cat api.log | grep 'calling' | wc -l

Comment: `-bash: watch: command not found`, macOS 10.14.1

Comment: `brew install watch`

Answer (score 124):

You can also use this command in terminal, apart from [nux's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/430383/618353):

```bsh
while true; do <your_command>; sleep <interval_in_seconds>; done
```

**Example:**

```bsh
while true; do ls; sleep 2; done
```

This command will print the output of `ls` at an interval of 2 sec.

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to stop the process.

**There are few drawbacks of `watch`:**

- It cannot use any aliased commands.
- If the output of any command is quite long, scrolling does not work properly.
- There is some trouble to set the [maximum time interval](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/36933/52402) beyond a certain value.
- `watch` will interpret ANSI color sequences passing escape characters using `-c` or `--color` option. For example output of `pygmentize` will work but it will fail for `ls --color=auto`.

In the above circumstances this may appear as a better option.

Comment: `watch` exists for that, this is a bit useless I would say

Comment: I am not claiming this answer is to be used at first
place. `watch` is good in most cases. That is why I
mentioned "apart from nux's answer" at the beginning. But there
are few problems with `watch` for example One **can not use any
aliased commands with `watch`**. Take for example `ll` which is
aliased to `ls -laF` but can not be used with `watch`.  Also in
case if the output of any command is quite long you will be in
trouble in scrolling using `watch`. In these few special cases this
answer may appear a better option.

Comment: @souravc My version of `watch` at least allows the `-c` or `--color` options for colorized output.

Comment: @IstvanChung I was saying without adding this `--color` option. with `--color` option `watch` will interpret ANSI color sequences passing escape characters.for example output of `pygmentize` but it will fail in case of `ls --color=auto`. I should have been mentioned that. thanks anyway.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of `while [[ true ]]`. Sure, it works, but so would `while [[ false ]]`.

Comment: @Dennis you can also use `while true` only without `[[]]` it will work. but only `while false` will not. when you put anything inside `[[]]` it will work. for example `[[ foo ]]`. It is just giving you an infinite loop.

Comment: Precisely my point. `[[ true ]]` makes it look it it's doing something it doesn't. That can be confusing to somebody unfamiliar with bash.

Comment: `while sleep x` is better - it's easier to kill.

Comment: @d33tah yes it will sleep first then do the action. Good in the sense it will reduce one instruction. Thanks

Comment: @BrunoPereira My problem is that my command has a `(` char in a path, and `watch` fails to parse it correctly even when escaped.

Comment: @nipponese then you are not escaping it correctly.

Comment: This is a nice alternative and, unlike `watch`, it keeps the command history.

Comment: Another weirdness with `watch` is that if I resize my terminal window, it runs the command again.

Comment: @BrunoPereira `watch exists for that, this is a bit useless I would say`.. really? Does it work on mac system? I have mac with zsh, it says `zsh: command not found: watch`. (pls read the question, its about terminal, that exists on Mac as well.

Answer (score 40):

Just wanted to pitch in to [sourav c.](https://askubuntu.com/a/430386/618353)'s and [nux](https://askubuntu.com/a/430383/618353)'s answers:

1. While `watch` will work perfectly on Ubuntu, you might want to avoid that if you want your "Unix-fu" to be pure. On FreeBSD for example, `watch` is a command to "snoop on another tty line".
2. `while true; do command; sleep SECONDS; done` also has a caveat: your command might be harder to kill using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. You might prefer:

   ```
   while sleep SECONDS; do command; done
   ```

   It's not only shorter, but also easier to interrupt. The caveat is that it will first sleep, then run your command, so you'll need to wait some `SECONDS` before the first occurrence of the command will happen.

Comment: Why exactly does it matter where you put `sleep` in the `while` loop? I couldn't find any difference, Ctrl+C broke the loop *instantly* no matter what.

Comment: @dessert: depends on what you're trying to break out from I guess. Normally, ctrl+c would just kill your `command` and `sleep` and only break if you kill `true`.

Comment: This worked, "watch" just sat there. I even made a script to remove the alias'd parts. no dice. The while statement is simple and gives what i need for monitoring when a cron job finishes.

Answer (score 14):

Sounds like the ideal task for the `cron` daemon which allows for running periodic commands. Run the `crontab -e` command to start editing your user's cron configuration. Its format is documented in [crontab(5)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/crontab.5). Basically you have five time-related, space-separated fields followed by a command:

```
The time and date fields are:

       field          allowed values
       -----          --------------
       minute         0-59
       hour           0-23
       day of month   1-31
       month          1-12 (or names, see below)
       day of week    0-7 (0 or 7 is Sunday, or use names)
```

For example, if you would like to run a Python script on every Tuesday, 11 AM:

```
0 11 * * 1 python ~/yourscript.py
```

There are also some special names that replace the time, like `@reboot`. Very helpful if you need to create a temporary directory. From my crontab (listed with `crontab -l`):

```
# Creates a temporary directory for ~/.distcc at boot
@reboot ln -sfn "$(mktemp -d "/tmp/distcc.XXXXXXXX")" "$HOME/.distcc"
```

Comment: The question asks how to run something periodically in the terminal.  `cron` runs behind the scenes rather than in the terminal

Answer (score 6):

you can use crontab. run the command `crontab -e` and open it with your preferred  text editor, then add this line

```
*/10 * * * *  /path-to-your-command
```

This will run your command every 10 minutes

```
* */4 * * *  /path-to-your-command
```

This will run your command every 4 hours

#### Another possible solution

```
$ ..some command...; for i in $(seq X); do $cmd; sleep Y; done
```

**X** number of times to repeat.

**Y** time to wait to repeat.

Example :

```
$ echo; for i in $(seq 5); do $cmd "This is echo number: $i"; sleep 1;done
```

Comment: Why is this an improvement? You just added an extra, needless, step by saving the command as a variable. The only things this does is i) make it longer to type ii) forces you to use only simple commands, no pipes or redirects etc.

Comment: Remove the extra variable

Answer (score 5):

If you are monitoring the file system, then `inotifywait` is brilliant and certainly adds less load on your system.

Example :

In **1st** terminal type this command :

```
$ inotifywait .
```

Then in **2nd** terminal, any command that affects the current directory,

```
$ touch newfile
```

Then in original terminal inotifywait will wake up and report the event

```
./ CREATE newfile2
```

Or in a loop

```
$ while true ; do inotifywait . ; done
Setting up watches.  
Watches established.
./ OPEN newfile2
Setting up watches.  
Watches established.
./ OPEN newfile2
Setting up watches.  
Watches established.
./ DELETE newfile
Setting up watches.  
Watches established.
./ CREATE,ISDIR newdir
Setting up watches.  
Watches established.
```

Comment: the user told you , no script , and maybe he dont want to monitor anything

Comment: I didn't tell him to write a script, I suggested that if they are looping inorder to watch for particular filesystem event, then inotifywait is useful, and uses less resources than repeating a command. I often run several commands on a command line eg `grep something InALogFile|less` is that a script ?

Comment: its a good answer , try to edit it to look more simple .

Comment: What could be simpler than `.` I can't leave out the command.

Comment: Thanks @XTian, a great command. I also now saw in the man page that you can add `-m` to continually monitor without a loop.

Answer (score 5):

You can create your own `repeat` command doing the following steps; [credits here](http://www.stefanoforenza.com/how-to-repeat-a-shell-command-n-times/):

First, open your `.bash_aliases` file:

```
$ xdg-open ~/.bash-aliases
```

Second, paste these lines at the bottom of the file and save:

```
repeat() {
n=$1
shift
while [ $(( n -= 1 )) -ge 0 ]
do
    "$@"
done
}
```

Third, either close and open again your terminal, or type:

```
$ source ~/.bash_aliases
```

Et voilà ! You can now use it like this:

```
$ repeat 5 echo Hello World !!!
```

or

```
$ repeat 5 ./myscript.sh
```

Comment: there is a small typo in the line xdg-open ~/.bash-aliases. it should be: xdg-open ~/.bash_aliases  (ie: underscore)

Answer (score 4):

Another concern with the "watch" approach proposed above is that it does display the result only when the process is done.
"date;sleep 58;date" will display the 2 dates only after 59 seconds... If you start something running for 4 minutes, that display slowly multiple pages of content, you will not really see it.

On the other hand, the concern with the "while" approach is that it doesn't take the task duration into consideration.

```
while true; do script_that_take_between_10s_to_50s.sh; sleep 50; done
```

With this, the script will run sometime every minutes, sometime might take 1m40. So even if a cron will be able to run it every minutes, here, it will not.

So to see the output on the shell as it's generated and wait for the exact request time, you need to look at the time before, and after, and loop with the while.

Something like:

```
while ( true ); do
  echo Date starting `date`
  before=`date +%s`
  sleep `echo $(( ( RANDOM % 30 )  + 1 ))`
  echo Before waiting `date`
  after=`date +%s`
  DELAY=`echo "60-($after-$before)" | bc`
  sleep $DELAY
  echo Done waiting `date`
done
```

This will output this:

As you can see, the command runs every minutes:

```
Date starting Mon Dec 14 15:49:34 EST 2015
Before waiting Mon Dec 14 15:49:52 EST 2015
Done waiting Mon Dec 14 15:50:34 EST 2015

Date starting Mon Dec 14 15:50:34 EST 2015
Before waiting Mon Dec 14 15:50:39 EST 2015
Done waiting Mon Dec 14 15:51:34 EST 2015
```

So just replace the "sleep `echo $(( ( RANDOM % 30 )  + 1 ))`" command with what ever you want and that will be run, on the terminal/shell, exactly every minute. If you want another schedule, just change the "60" seconds with what ever you need.

Shorter version without the debug lines:

```
while ( true ); do
  before=`date +%s`
  sleep `echo $(( ( RANDOM % 30 )  + 1 ))` # Place you command here
  after=`date +%s`
  DELAY=`echo "60-($after-$before)" | bc`
  sleep $DELAY
done
```

Comment: Replying to myself... If your command takes more than the delay you configure, $DELAY will get a negative value and the sleep command will fail so the script will restart right away. Need to be aware of that.