# Is it important to install disk monitor on linux?

Tags: bash, software-recommendation, disk-usage

As a linux system security administrator & server manager?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you want, but you might find it in Conky.

Answer (score 4):

Please open System Monitor. Select the File Systems tab. There you will see the current disk usage.

[image]

You can also do so from the terminal:

```
df -h
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of command line tools, such as [`du`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/du) or [`df`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/df).

For example, `df -k` is a commonly used command to see how full disks are:

```
$ df -k
Filesystem    1024-blocks      Used Available Capacity   iused    ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1s5    111908412  23512176  88140236    22%   5942042 22035059   21%   /
devfs                 194       194         0   100%       674        0  100%   /dev
map -hosts              0         0         0   100%         0        0  100%   /net
map auto_home           0         0         0   100%         0        0  100%   /home
/dev/disk0s2    155012040 113711612  41300428    74%  28427901 10325107   73%   /Volumes/Mavericks
/dev/disk0s3    758769528 723428084  35341444    96% 180857019  8835361   95%   /Volumes/Leopard
/dev/disk0s4      9634344   6973536   2660808    73%   1743382   665202   72%   /Volumes/Kali
/dev/disk0s5     52617544  32891708  19725836    63%   8222925  4931459   63%   /Volumes/Snow
/dev/disk1s2    155866920  74914824  80952096    49%  18728704 20238024   48%   /Volumes/Japan1
/dev/disk1s3     96795760  11501344  85294416    12%   2875334 21323604   12%   /Volumes/Yosemite
/dev/disk1s7    122078968  12744944 109334024    11%   3186234 27333506   10%   /Volumes/SnowServ
```

To have a constant updating report (see [Repeat a command every x interval of time in terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/430382/repeat-a-command-every-x-interval-of-time-in-terminal)), you could use it in conjunction with [`watch`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/watch), so for example:

```
watch -d 5 df -k
```

will give you an output that is updated every five seconds.

Answer (score 1):

**GNOME disk usage analyzer**

An easy to use GUI tool to analyze use of storage space. It is my prefered way of analyzing disk space usage.

```
sudo apt-get install baobab
```

[image: baobab]

**df - to check file system disk space usage**

```
reversiblean@lenovo-g50:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           385M  6.5M  378M   2% /run
/dev/sda4        25G   16G  7.5G  68% /
tmpfs           1.9G   58M  1.9G   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2        96M   32M   65M  34% /boot/efi
/dev/sda5       260G  258G  1.2G 100% /home
tmpfs           385M   60K  385M   1% /run/user/100
```

**du command**

To estimate files and directory sizes in a recursive manner.

```
reversiblean@lenovo-g50:~$ sudo du --max-depth=1 --human-readable /
145M    /boot
262G    /home
88M     /etc
4.0K    /media
16M     /bin
504K    /dev
572M    /lib
4.0K    /lib64
0       /mnt
3.2G    /opt
0       /proc
23M     /root
6.5M    /run
15M     /sbin
0       /srv
0       /sys
24K     /tmp
9.1G    /usr
0       /cdrom
2.9G    /var
3.8M    /lib32
278G    /
```

Use the `--summarize` flag to display only a total

```
reversiblean@lenovo-g50:~$ du --summarize --human-readable ~/Videos/Movies/
79G /home/reversiblean/Videos/Movies/
```