# xdotool How do I automate click to click 30 times each delayed by 30 secs then repeat again hourly?

Tags: xdotool

Here is a code I have tried:

```
while sleep 3600; do xdotool mousemove xxx yyy click --repeat 30 --delay 60000 1; done
```

- --clearmodifiers       - reset active modifiers (alt, etc) while typing
- --window WINDOW        - specify a window to send click to
- --repeat REPEATS       - number of times times to click. Default is 1
- --delay MILLISECONDS   - delay in milliseconds between clicks.

  This has no effect if you do not use --repeat.
  Default is 100ms

So what I am looking for is 30 clicks each delayed by 60 seconds then for the whole process to start again in an hour. When I enter this into terminal flags are not recognized. --repeat nor --delay

Comment: I'm familiar with parts of `xdotool`, but not `--repeat`. What does this code do exactly? Is it not what you're looking for? Please [edit] to clarify. By the way, welcome to Ask Ubuntu!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Repeat a command every x interval of time in terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/q/430382/301745)

Comment: Edited it. it it was just what i attempted for what i was trying to do. what do you suggest?

Comment: Why are you editing your question to remove formatting? It's very difficult to read without formatting.

Comment: This question has been modified many times. Each edit removes formatting and changes the overall scope of the question making it very difficult to work with.

Comment: I fixed it now. I was doing a couple things at once. Do you know why the flags I'm using arent being recognized.

Answer (score 0):

Your script looks mostly correct, but the `--delay` is in millseconds not seconds, and it appears this option actually controls the delay in between repeats. You can use `sleep 60s` instead to delay the initial click.

```
--delay MILLISECONDS
    Specify how long, in milliseconds, to delay between clicks. This option is not
    used if the --repeat flag is set to 1 (default).
```

Comment: yea repeat flag isnt working neither is delay.

Comment: i think i figured it out i set the flag in the wrong spot think its suppose to be click --delay -- repeat 1 what i did was click 1 --delay --repeat